# Replace the text inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this snippet of code and I would like to replace the "ARRIVAL" text which is between the top and lower level `<div>` element but I can't figure out a way.

I don't want to use `replaceWith` , `html` or similar methods on `<div class="left booktext">` because that would replace the rest of html elements. There is an event handler attached to `input class="bookfields"` and I don't want to lose that. Unfortunately, there is no event delegation.

```
<div class="left booktext">
  ARRIVAL       
  <div class="bookborder">
    <input type="hidden" name="checkin" value="2014-03-05">
    <input type="text" class="bookfields hasDatepicker" style="width:65px;" id="checkin-select" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: `$('.left.booktext').get(0).childNodes[0].textContent = "New text";`

Comment: Awesome thanks! Can you change it so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: don't know much jquery.. so converted to javascript :)

Comment: @george my solution is similar to what Felix shown below. please do that.

Comment: sorry, I've read bad.. i update answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)** along with **[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**:

```
$('.left').contents().first().replaceWith("New Text");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDkV7/)**

Answer (score 1):

In pure Javascript:

```
var books = document.querySelectorAll('.booktext');
for (var i = 0, length = books.length; i < length; i++) {
    books[i].firstChild.data = "your text";
}
```

Easier with jQuery though:

```
$('.booktext').contents().first().replaceWith("your text");
```

**Advice**
Is better put text in a span element, with all the benefits of the case.
In this way you can put your text in any order inside div, like:

```
<div class="left booktext">
  <div class="bookborder">
    <input type="hidden" name="checkin" value="2014-03-05">
    <span>ARRIVAL</span>        
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

And than replace with:

```
$('.bookborder span').text('my new text');
```

Comment: I can't see pure javascript answer.. ops!

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript you can access a text node like this

```
var bookText = document.querySelector(".booktext");
bookText.firstChild.nodeValue = "Some other text";
```

see it working here 
http://codepen.io/sajjad26/pen/JkAms